# Getting more then just the first item in JSON array using CHOETL converting JSON to CSV

Tags: json, vb.net, csv, choetl

Been struggling with the following:  I have a JSON response of orders from our Ecommerce website (Shopify).  I need to create a CSV from the response.  Everything is fine for me until I get to the line item details.  I only get the first item in the array.  I have seen other solutions that showed the other array items as additional columns however I need to see these as rows.  A lot of examples I have seen are also in C# which I am not great with.

**Order Class**

```
Imports ChoETL

Public Class Order
    <ChoJSONRecordField>
    Public Property Name As String
    <ChoJSONRecordField>
    Public Property Email As String
    <ChoJSONRecordField(JSONPath:="financial_status")>
    Public Property Financial_Status As String
    <ChoJSONRecordField(JSONPath:="line_items[*].title")>
    Public Property Title As String

End Class
```

**Create CSV sub**

```
Private Shared Sub UsingPOCO()
    Using csv = New ChoCSVWriter("order3.csv").WithFirstLineHeader()

        Using json = New ChoJSONReader(Of Order)("order2.json")
            csv.Write(json)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

**Sample JSON**

```
{
  "email": "anemail@adomain.com",
  "financial_status": "paid",
  "name": "#CCC94440",
  "line_items": [
    {
      "title": "product1",
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "title": "product2",
      "quantity": 2
    },
    {
      "title": "product3",
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**CSV Output**

[image]

**What I need**

[image]

**OR**

[image]

**Update #1**
I have found this answer on another question that seems to be on the track I want.  However I can't figure out how to convert it to VB.net.  The answer I believe will work is the selected answer update #2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57166153/2037475

**Update #2**
I was able to convert the C# from the other answer to VB.net....  However I get the following error which I am still looking into: "'Select' is not a member of 'Dynamic()'"

```
    Using fw = New StreamWriter("order3.csv", True)

        Using w = New ChoCSVWriter(fw).WithFirstLineHeader()

            Using r = New ChoJSONReader("order2.json").WithJSONPath("$.line_items[*]")
                w.Write(r.SelectMany(Function(r1) (CType(r1.line_items, Dynamic())).[Select](Function(r2) New With {r1.name, r2.title})))
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText("order3.csv"))
```

**Update 3**

I dont need to stick with CHOETL its just the first thing I found that I had success with.  Open to any suggestions.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Does it have to be CHOETL?

Comment: No, if you know of something else that'll work I am open...  most of what I have seen used choetl thats why I went that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working sample of it in VB.NET

```
        Dim json As String

        json = "
{
  ""email"": ""anemail@adomain.com"",
  ""financial_status"": ""paid"",
  ""name"": ""#CCC94440"",
  ""line_items"": [
    {
      ""title"": ""product1"",
      ""quantity"": 3
    },
    {
      ""title"": ""product2"",
      ""quantity"": 2
    },
    {
      ""title"": ""product3"",
      ""quantity"": 1
    }
  ]
}"
        Dim csv As New StringBuilder

        Using w = New ChoCSVWriter(csv).WithFirstLineHeader()
            Using r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json)
                w.Write(r.SelectMany(Function(r1) (CType(r1.line_items, Object())).[Select](Function(r2) New With {r1.email, r1.financial_status, r1.name, r2.title, r2.quantity})))
            End Using
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString())
```

**Output:**

```
email,financial_status,name,title,quantity
anemail@adomain.com,paid,#CCC94440,product1,3
anemail@adomain.com,paid,#CCC94440,product2,2
anemail@adomain.com,paid,#CCC94440,product3,1
```

**UPDATE #1:**

To retrieve price from shipping items

```
        json = "
{
  ""email"": ""email@email.com"",
  ""financial_status"": ""paid"",
  ""name"": ""#CCC94440"",
  ""line_items"": [
    {
      ""title"": ""item0"",
      ""quantity"": 3
    },
    {
      ""title"": ""item1"",
      ""quantity"": 2
    }
  ],
  ""shipping_lines"": [
    {
      ""title"": ""Free Shipping"",
      ""price"": ""1.00""
    }
  ]
}
"
        Dim csv As New StringBuilder

        Using w = New ChoCSVWriter(csv).WithFirstLineHeader()
            Using r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json)
                w.Write(r.SelectMany(Function(r1) CType(r1.line_items, Object()).[Select](Function(r2)
                                                                                              Return New With
                                                                                                {
                                                                                                    r1.email,
                                                                                                    r1.financial_status,
                                                                                                    r1.name,
                                                                                                    r2.title,
                                                                                                    r2.quantity,
                                                                                                    CType(r1.shipping_lines, Object())(0).price
                                                                                                }
                                                                                          End Function)))
            End Using
        End Using

        Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString())
```

**Output:**

```
email,financial_status,name,title,quantity,price
email@email.com,paid,#CCC94440,item0,3,1.00
email@email.com,paid,#CCC94440,item1,2,1.00
```

Comment: Hello Cinchoo,  All was going well until I came to another array I had to map.  In the JSON they put the shipping information in an array.  I tried r1.shipping_lines[0].price since I will always be taking the price from the first array object.  This didn't work any suggestions?

Comment: {
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "financial_status": "paid",
  "name": "#CCC94440",
  "line_items": [
    {
      "title": "item0",
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "title": "item1",
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ],
  "shipping_lines": [
    {
      "title": "Free Shipping",
      "price": "0.00"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Also tried the below in the hopes of figuring it out myself. 
 Unfortunately it throws the exception "No records found". 
          w.Write(r.Select(Function(r1) (CType(r1.shipping_lines, Object())).[SelectMany](Function(r2) (CType(r2.line_items, Object())).[Select](Function(r3) New With {r1.name, r1.email, r1.financial_status, r1.processed_at, r1.fulfillment_status, r1.updated_at, r1.buyer_accepts_marketing, r1.currency, r1.subtotal_price, r2.price, r3.title, r3.quantity}))))

Comment: I'm not sure if I should make a new question for this but as I was working away trying to figure out the above issue I came up with 2 more issues: 1) I found another couple of arrays I have to deal with....  A couple of which could be empty.  How would I deal with empty arrays?  2) Is it possible to set the column headings ie "Financial Status" instead of financial_status?  Sorry...  Should I create a new question or is it okay to ask here?

Comment: It would be infinitely preferable to endless comments that cannot support and form of decent code formatting...

Comment: @MatthewBrown, you will need to typecast `shipping_items` to object array before accessing `price`. Posted working sample above as `Update #1`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, with all your emerging requirements, it's going to get messier and messier to keep trying to ram all this into a single line of LINQ...

I'd head to jsonutils.com and paste the json there to turn it into VB, turn on PascalCase and JsonProperty attributes:

```
Public Class LineItem

    <JsonProperty("title")>
    Public Property Title As String

    <JsonProperty("quantity")>
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
End Class

Public Class ShippingLine

    <JsonProperty("title")>
    Public Property Title As String

    <JsonProperty("price")>
    Public Property Price As String
End Class

Public Class Example

    <JsonProperty("email")>
    Public Property Email As String

    <JsonProperty("financial_status")>
    Public Property FinancialStatus As String

    <JsonProperty("name")>
    Public Property Name As String

    <JsonProperty("line_items")>
    Public Property LineItems As LineItem()

    <JsonProperty("shipping_lines")>
    Public Property ShippingLines As ShippingLine()
End Class
```

Then some loops are a tad more readable:

```
'inside Using w....

Dim root = NewtonSoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(your_json_string)

For Each li in root.LineItems

    Dim csvLineObject = New With { _
        root.email, _
        root.financial_status, _
        root.name, _
        li.title, _
        li.quantity, _
        root.ShippingLines.First().Price, _
        root.OtherArrayMightBeEmpty.FirstOrDefault()?.OtherProperty
    }
    w.Write(csvLineObject)

Next li
```

- 

Never used CHOETL, can probably get away with a similar construct on r (= root here)